# Need to substring by varchar length()

Tags: mysql, substr

I need to substring varchar by its length.

```
select
substr('abcdefg', 1, 3),
substr('가나다라마바사', 1, 3)
from dual;
```

This returns

```
en  ko
abc 가나다
```

But what I need is

```
en  ko
abc 가
```

Because the length of 'abc' and '가' is 3.

Hope there's a function what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is there always a *2 factor between nr of English characters and whatever-this-language-is characters ?

Comment: Bartdude// Each Korean letter has 3bytes while English's 1byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a function to solve your problem:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BIT_SUBSTR;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION BIT_SUBSTR(var TEXT,i INT,l INT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE var2 TEXT;
    SET var2 = SUBSTR(var, i, (l/CAST(BIT_LENGTH(substr(var,1,1))/8 AS UNSIGNED)));
    RETURN var2;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And then you could use it instead SUBSTR e.g.:

```
mysql> select BIT_SUBSTR('가나다라마바사', 1, 3), BIT_SUBSTR('abcdefg', 1, 3);
+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| BIT_SUBSTR('가나다라마바사', 1, 3)        | BIT_SUBSTR('abcdefg', 1, 3) |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 가                                        | abc                         |
+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what the problem is, but it seems you are having issues with length relating to multi-byte characters.

Instead of `LENGTH()` you could use `CHAR_LENGTH()` to determine string length.  `CHAR_LENGTH()` takes into account multi-byte characters ([CHAR_LENGTH docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)) where as `LENGTH()` is returning the length of the string in bytes.  In your case the Korean would have a `CHAR_LENGTH() = 7` but a `LENGTH() = 21` (assuming 3 bytes per character)

You could use some combination of `FLOOR( CHAR_LENGTH() / LENGTH() * @desiredNumberOfBytes )` to return the number of characters relating to a specific number of bytes, but this may then result in a non-integer number of characters (hence use of `FLOOR`, though `ROUND` or `CEILING` may also be used).

As you have already seen, `SUBSTRING()` is already multi-byte safe.

I'm afraid that for a more specific answer I'll need some clarification as to what you are trying to achieve though.

Comment: My problem is, I can't substring exactly varchar by 3bytes(or more). I know how `CHAR_LENGTH()` works but I can't make them work together in my case..

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I am still not really understanding the question.  I can see what you have asked for but it feels like you are describing 1 example without describing precisely what problem it's trying to solve.  It makes it hard to offer accurate advice